# UDP Packet loss simulation & probability

Tags: sockets, udp, lan

I am currently creating a server software that communicates with multiple arduino boards. Due to the hardware, I am using the UDP Protocol. I have a pretty simple mechanism that will resend packages in most of the cases when they get lost. I have two questions now:

How probable is it that UDP Packets get lost in a Network with no Internet access and about 20 arduinos and one computer? Is it even neccessary to have a resend method?

Is there a way I can simulate UDP Packet loss in this network to check if the resend mechanisms are working?

Comment: I'd say the probability of losing a packet would depend on your network, the router the arduinos themselves the kind of wiring (or Wi-Fi), the distance between the nodes, etc... And whether you need to resend depends on what you are doing. For some things losing a packet is no big deal and can be ignored for some other it  might be worth re-sending.

Comment: The arduinos are all wired using the official Ethernet Shield (the one without TCP). The cable lengths are about 4m and its a managed switch from TP-Link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How probable is it that UDP Packets get lost in a Network with no
>   Internet access and about 20 arduinos and one computer?

The probability is 100% that sooner or later a packet will be dropped.

If you want a more detailed statistic, like the probability of a packet being dropped within any particular period of time, the only real way to know is to try it and found out (using e.g. sequence numbers in the packets so that the receiver(s) can detect when a packet has been dropped by noting the skipped sequence-number).  The probability will depend very much on the size of the packets, the speed at which the packets are being sent, the CPU speed of the receivers, what other tasks the receivers are spending CPU time on, the quality of your Ethernet switch, the quality of your Ethernet cables, the phase of the moon, etc etc.

> Is it even neccessary to have a resend method?

That depends on what the consequences would be to having a packet dropped.  For some applications (e.g. streaming audio or video, or audio-metering data), dropping a packet is no big deal; you just ignore the fact that some data was lost, and continue on with the next packet as usual.  For other applications (e.g. file transmit/receive), the loss of a packet means the loss of data that the receiver needs, so you'll want to have some way to recover from that loss, e.g. by detecting it and triggering a resend, or else the entire transfer will fail (or at least the receiver will end up with only a partial file).

> Is there a way I can simulate UDP Packet loss in this network to check
>   if the resend mechanisms are working?

Sure, just put some logic into the receivers so that they occasionally pretend to not have received a packet:

```
int numBytesReceived = recv(...);
if ((rand()%100) == 0)   // Simulate a 1% packet loss rate
{
    printf("Pretending to have dropped a packet!\n");
}
else
{ 
    // handle the incoming packet as usual
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!